# How to set values for a multidimensional array in vb?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I would like to do something like this to my array `dim TrainingData(3,2) = {0,0,0},{0,1,0},{1,0,0},{1,1,1}` obviously this code doesn't work but basically what I want to do is this 
`TrainingDat(0,0)=0,TrainingData(0,1)=0,TrainingData(0,2)=0,TrainingData(1,0)=0,TrainingData(1,1)=1 ect...`
But in a much less annoying way something like my first line of code. I don't want to have to use a loop unless it is Absolutely Necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help you figure it out.

```
    Dim mda As Integer(,) = New Integer(3, 2) {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}
```

Comment: @MrQandA here is a good reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx